# How do I get Python to see libtorrent-rasterbar in mac os?

Tags: python, macos

I try to install libtorrent-rasterbar, but Python does not see the module. The El Captaine system. Tell me where to look?

```
andrew: ~ $ brew install python3
Warning: python3-3.6.0_1 already installed
andrew: ~ $ brew install libtorrent-rasterbar
Warning: libtorrent-rasterbar-1.1.1 already installed
andrew: ~ $ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Mar  4 2017, 12:32:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
>>>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For python2 it work: https://gist.github.com/jacobzelek/ecb6e98feb91d911e231
May be for python3 is similarly

Comment: Please, elaborate your question more so others can provide the solution.